# Dynamically construct list of all objects in package/directory

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a directory containing all display types and I need to expose these types via an API. This set of display types will grow significantly over this application's lifecycle, so it'd be nice if adding a new type didn't require adding new code to our service layer.

So in a scenario where a subdir `src/domain/types/` contains `Type1.js`, `Type2.js`, `Type3.js`, and `Type4.js`, is it possible to have a piece of code that instantiates all these types and adds those to some array? Something like:

```
// I know this line won't work, but you get the idea
const dir = require('../src/domain/types/')


getAllDisplayTypes() {
    const types = []
    for (const type in dir) {
        // auto-magically create new type
        types.push(someMagicallyCreatedType)
    }
    return types
}
```

where `types` would be an array where each entry is a set of default values created in the constructor of `TypeX.js`.

Alternatively, if you have  a creative way to expose a set of domain object definitions, I'm all ears.

Comment: Do I understand correct that you want to get list of all `(Type)[1-9](\.js)` files in a directory?

Comment: That's not what they're actually called, I changed the names to simplify. Assume arbitrary naming. Most importantly is the ability to dynamically instantiate some type without actually knowing what it is.

Comment: why don't you use `fs.readdir`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Using a package called `require-dir` that let's you require an entire directory, I was able to use some JS devilry to get this working:

```
const require_dir = require('require-dir')
const allTypes = require_dir('../domain/types/')

//  ...

getDisplayTypes() {
    const types = {}
    for (const typeName of Object.keys(allTypes)) {
        const typeConstructor = allTypes[typeName]
        const typeInstance = new typeConstructor()
        types[typeName] = typeInstance
    }
    return types
}
```